# javascript/html5 create custom event

Tags: javascript, html, events

Say I have a variable "stateName," (or rather a className in my exact case) and every time the value of stateName changes, which might be for any of myriad reasons, I want the program to respond in a uniform way.

I am thinking that I want to create an event "stateChanged" and an eventListener that listens for this change and executes a function accordingly?

I don't really know how to make custom events in javascript though, and I also don't know if this is a good approach.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a setter function so you never manipulate it directly, and then you can generate a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) for it. If it has to trigger even when "something else" changes the value, you need to use something more powerful like [mutation observing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: I didn't know about mutation observing, seems like it is what I am looking for here, and is generally good to know about.  thanks!